# Изменение объекта в очереди multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, multiprocessing

Код:

```
import multiprocessing
import shelve


class Report:
    __report = ''

    def __init__(self):
        self.__report = ''

    def write(self, rep):
        self.__report += '\n' + rep

    def get_all(self):
        return self.__report

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.__report + '\n' + str(other)
        return self

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.__report += '\n' + str(other)
        return self


def proc(q):
    r = Report()
    q.put(r)
    r += 'first'
    with shelve.open('123') as ssion:
        r += 'second'

    print(r.get_all())
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    que = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc, args=(que,))
    p.start()
    while p.is_alive():
        continue
    print('q', que.get().get_all())
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

```
first
second
q 
first
second
```

**Полученный результат:**

```
first
second
q 
first
```

Мне необходимо внутри процесса изменять объект, подобный объекту Report, как это показано в коде выше. Но эти изменения работают только до блока with, всё, что происходит с объектом дальше, не работает. Я думаю, что это моя глупая ошибка, но не знаю даже примерно, в чём она может состоять. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: вопрос только в том, почему вы думаете что любые изменения после `q.put(r)` обязаны быть видны в другом процессе

Comment: Вот я про это и спрашиваю, я же в очередь ссылку на объект добавляю? Или как это вообще работает?

Comment: в сторону: сперва нужно получить данные (`q.get()`), а потом ждать пока процесс завершится (`p.join()`) иначе deadlock может возникнуть, если посылаемый объект больше pipe  буфера.

Comment: @jfs спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый процесс имеет свою память. Когда вы что-то кладёте в `multiprocessing.Queue` в одном процессе, а потом вынимаете в другом, то между этими событиями  ваш объект сериализуется в последовательность байт,  которая уже и отправляется из одного процесса в другой, на другом конце последовательность байт превращается (с помощью pickle) в объект.

Поэтому любые изменения в одном процессе, после того как объект отправлен, не будут видны принимаемой стороной в другом процессе (потому что это другой объект, просто с похожим значением).

Точный момент отправки не специфицирован, он происходит в другом потоке, поэтому какие-то изменения и после возвращения `put(r)` могут быть видны (как с `first` в примере в вопросе). Не нужно на это рассчитывать. К примеру, если добавить `time.sleep(1)` после `q.put(r)`, то `first` так же как и `second` не успевает в объект попасть.

Comment: Я так и думал, но почему первая запись ("first") отображается?

Comment: @vladF точный момент когда объект в байты превращается  не специфицирован (где-то между put и get) так как в отдельном потоке данные передаются.